# Regex: Grab the string between the 4th and 5th colon

Tags: grok

I'm trying to find a regex that will grab the string between the 4th and 4th colon.

Example event:

```
cpe:2.3:a:libexpat_project:libexpat:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
```

Expected outcome:

```
libexpat
```

Solution:

I used GROK to parse this out.

```
%{WORD}[:]%{BASE10NUM}[:]%{WORD}[:]%{WORD}[:]%{WORD:[software][name]}
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `^(?:[^:]+:){4}\K[^:]+`. Depending on whether your engine support the reset.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @onyambu Thank you. The regex you provided works perfectly using simple online regex testers. However, when I attempted to implement this in a grok filter in Logstash I ran into some problems with the round brackets which is causing the filter to misbehave and match on too much.

This is my syntax:

`grok {
  match => { "[software][cpe]" => "(?<[software][name]>^(?:[^:]+:){4}\K[^:]+)"
}`


From what I understand, the grok filter requires these brackets but I'm currently troubleshooting a workaround. If you have some insights on how to get around this, that would be great.

Comment: what is the purpose of having `(?<[software][name]>...`?? YOU Cannot have the BEGINNING of the word be in the middle of the sentence if that even makes sence. ie the caret `^` shows the BEGINNING of the sentence yet you have it in the middle of the regex. That does not make any sence. You must always have `^` be at the beginning of the regex unless you have the flags or it is a literal caret. the part `software[name]` does not make sense. I do not know `grok` but your problem is how to use the regex I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to grok

```
%{WORD}[:]%{BASE10NUM}[:]%{WORD}[:]%{WORD}[:]%{WORD:[software][name]}
```